# Change DateFormatString to show 11:59:59 as opposed to 12:00:00

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle

This is a very simple issue, although I don't know how to best solve it.  I have to 2 fields:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="AUCTIONBEGINS" HeaderText="Auction Begins" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False" >
<asp:BoundField DataField="AUCTIONENDS" HeaderText="Auction Ends" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False" >
```

My problem is that the values you assign to these two fields get written to an Oracle database but I want them to be written in the following manner:
for AUCTIONBEGINS --->  1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM
for AUCTIONENDS ---> 1/10/2013 11:59:59 PM

Is there an easy way to hardcode this into the DataFormatString? Or should I do it on the server side before writing to the database?

EDIT* Sorry for not being too clear. Both fields get saved with the 12:00:00 AM timestamp at the end, I want to implicitly add the 11:59:59 PM on the AUCTIONENDS DataField

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean - but the *database* fields should just be DATETIME fields (or whatever); there's really no such thing as a format at that point.

Comment: What value is stored in the database? 1/11/2013 12:00:00 AM?

Comment: Sorry for not being too clear.  Both fields get saved with the 12:00:00 AM timestamp at the end, I want to implicitly add the 11:59:59 PM on the AUCTIONENDS DataField

Comment: -1: please define what "fastest" mean (or remove from question) - do you need code that is fast to write? take minimal amount of server side time? minimal bandwidth between server and Oracle box? something else?

Comment: I meant fastest as in least amount of code.  I just removed it from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add -1 seconds to the date:

```
auctionEnd = auctionEnd.AddSeconds(-1);
```

This will turn, for example, 1/10/2013 12:00:00 AM into 1/9/2013 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: This would work. However, this is the way I'm saving the date on the database:

(cmd.Parameters.Add("In_AuctionEnds", OracleType.DateTime).Value = auctionEnds.Text;)

Comment: Would I need to convert my auctionEnds.Text to a date element?

Comment: @Jose Yes. You could just do `var auctionEnd = DateTime.Parse(auctionEnds.Text).AddSeconds(-1);`

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is the 11:59:59 PM, I usually do something like

```
    EndDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

This will give you the last second of the day of the date.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is the 11:59:59 PM, best practice now is, for me, to use:

```
EndDate.Add(DateTime.MaxValue.TimeOfDay)
```

insteand of:

```
EndDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)
```

[image]